# Best practice to use ADO.NET with design patterns?

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have something like following

```
...
public DataTable GetList()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();      
        // select from table 
    }
}

public void Insert()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();      
        // Insert into table
    }
}

...
```

Is there a way to define connection string as global variable, and dispose it after operations?

```
// connection open

...

public DataTable GetList()
{
    // use global connection
}

public void Insert()
{
    // use global connection
}

...

// connection close
```

How can I do this? Which design Pattern can I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible

```
 public class MyClass:IDisposable
{
    SqlConnection myCon;

    public MyClass() 
    {
        myCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    public DataTable GetList()
    {
        // use global connection
    }

    public void Insert()
    {
        // use global connection
    }



    public void Dispose()
    {
        myCon.Close();
    }
}
```

Using:

```
 using (MyClass myclass = new MyClass())
        {
           DataTable dt = myclass.GetList();
        }
```

Comment: good sample. While it answers the question it also does explain the usage of "using" keyword for disposable class

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you're using SQL Server, it's not considered good practice to keep connections open like that.

ADO.Net provides a feature called ConnectionPooling. Once you open a connection, it will check the pool. If an existing connection with the same connection string can be found, it is returned from the pool so the setup time is *very* short.

When you close a connection it is returned to the pool.

This is very efficient and makes connecting to the database very quick.

EDIT

Here is an MSDN article on the topic. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Comment: The pattern he uses in the first fragment is fine imo. DbConnection implements IDisposable which closes the connection at the end of the using statement.

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi I've added a link to an MSDN article in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I read it before, but I did not understand, after your comment I read again and now I mostly understand...

Comment: Great. It's a topic well worth understanding as keeping connections open can eventually starve the connection pool and your application can stop working :(